# If statement in user defined function not working

Tags: python, pandas, function, if-statement, valueerror

I have the following dataframe:

```
    SGCODE                  X            Y
0   T0IQ00000000017200015   27.687276   -26.001460
1   T0IQ00000000017200022   27.699453   -26.003298
2   T0IQ00000000017800128   27.753478   -26.047500
```

With a user defined function:

```
def haversine_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, rlim):
    r = 6371
    phi1 = np.radians(lat1)
    phi2 = np.radians(lat2)
    delta_phi = np.radians(lat2 - lat1)
    delta_lambda = np.radians(lon2 - lon1)
    a = np.sin(delta_phi / 2)**2 + np.cos(phi1) * np.cos(phi2) *   np.sin(delta_lambda / 2)**2
    res = r * (2 * np.arctan2(np.sqrt(a), np.sqrt(1 - a)))
    if rlim >= res:
        return np.round(res, 2)
```

When I try to run the function with the if-statement on the df, I'm getting the error below. When I remove the if-statement it works fine and I'm getting the output, am I missing something obvious with the if-statement syntax?

```
distances_km = []
for row in sample_unq_sg_codes_latlong.itertuples(index=False):
   distances_km.append(
       haversine_distance(sample_unq_sg_codes_latlong["X"], sample_unq_sg_codes_latlong["Y"], row.X, row.Y,5)
   )
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

However when I run a single of iteration of the function then it works:

```
haversine_distance(27.687276, -26.001460, 27.699453, -26.003298,5)
1.37
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add break point on line with if statement, or at least print out rlim and res. Probably your problem is that res and rlim are not int or floats, but array or something else.

Long story short: check type of 2 things you are compering and ensure outcome of that comparison is bool (and not series)

Comment: Thank you for the help @konserw, aw yes okay I see.
I added the following line:  'res2= float(res)' to ensure the comparing types are the same. 
In the terms of ensuring the outcome type, how can I ensure it's bool and not a series?

Comment: if compering 2 floats result is for sure bool; when compering other types, you would need to check documentation of those types (for example array).

You could also store result of comparison in variable and check it's type with isinstance(var, bool) or print type with print(type(var))

Answer (score 0):

You may get numpy array as condition of 'if'.

Any one of rlim and res is np array, then the result of comparison will also be numpy array.

That's why it request you to use any (any one True) or all (all true) for condition of 'if'.